# Convert to double - questionable accuracy

Tags: vb.net, double

I'm using `Convert.ToDouble(value)` to convert an OleDbDataReader type to Double but sometimes it adds extra decimals (I'm working with Access).

Example:

Lets say `data(0)` is holding the value 69,8 (with comma)

Then this is my code:

```
Dim data As OleDbDataReader = DBBroker.getInstance.read("SELECT ......")

Dim m as Double = Convert.ToDouble(data(0))
```

My problem is that this is making `m` something like 69.80002302 (or something similar) instead of just 69.8 like it really containss.

Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Your given example is [not reproducable](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5S2g55). As @JohnColeman wrote please give a real example of your code when you actually encounter this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the value in the database is exactly 69.8?  Some database tools may display the field formatted in such a way that it only *looks* like it contains 69.8, but really holds 69.80002302.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour when you use `CDbl(data(0))` or `CType(data(0), Double)`? Is `data(0)` a string?

Comment: I can't use methods like those. I can just use object oriented methods (strict option is ON)

Comment: @JohnColeman a double cannot hold 69.8 (or 62.8) without round-off error.

Comment: @Wrong What is the data type of the column with 69,8 in it?

Comment: That does not make sense. `CDbl` nor `CType` have no relation to either `option strict on` or "object-oriented restrictions", whatever that might be. Please try them and tell what happens.

Comment: @RickRegan You are of course correct. I was thinking of a mantissa of 698 with an exponent of -1: but temporarily forgot base 10 finite decimals are not always base 2 finite decimals. Still, the round-off error of the magnitude that OP was reporting made little sense.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's numeric.

Comment: @GSerg it does not let me compile with that :D

Comment: @JohnColeman Right, 69.80002302 is way too much error for a double. Many people make up such numbers to make their point about floating-point, so I've grown not to take them at face value (For the record, 69.8 rounds (correctly) to 69.799999999999971578290569595992565155029296875.)

Comment: @Wrong Instead of `Dim m as Double = Convert.ToDouble(data(0))` you can use `Dim m as Double = data.GetDouble(0)`. Which version of Access are you using? The only reference I found to a "Numeric" type is from Access 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you really sure that the field really contains exactly 69.8 or, simply, Access is rounding out the value?

If you really want to be extra sure about what's inside the reader, you can debug into the code and use `.IsDbNull(0)` to check if the value it's null. If it's not, look at the actual type of `data(0)` in the **Locals** tab in Visual Studio. If it's already a double, then no conversion is happening, and I suspect the field is already storing a rounded value.

Comment: Yes, I debugged and in the last line while data(0) was 69.8 it made m tha value I said. It's not really 69.8 (I don't remember what number it was, it's an example of what happened)

Comment: If it wasn't EXACTLY 69.8 it could be a simple rounding issue. Please provide the exact value.